# 'dict' object has no attribute 'y'. I am confused about what this means and how it can be fixed

Tags: python, plot

I am using odeint to solve a system of 6 equations. I am then wanting to save my solution into the variable x6a, y6a, z6a, x6b, y6b, z6b with the line:

```
x6_a, y6_a, z6_a, x6_b, y6_b, z6_b = sol6.y
```

but my code starts to fail at this point because of the error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Here is a minimal reproducable example of my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def coupled_jac(X, t, sigma, r, b, C1, C1x, S, O, C2, C2x, tau):
    jac = np.array([[-sigma, sigma, 0, -C1*X[3], 0, 0], [r+X[2], -1, -X[0], 0, C1*S, 0], [X[1], X[0], -b, 0, 0, C1x*S], [-tau*C2, 0, 0, -tau*sigma, tau*sigma, 0], [0, tau*C2, 0, tau*r-S*X[5], -r*tau, -tau*S*X[3]], [0, 0, tau*C2x, tau*S*X[4], tau*S*X[3], -b*tau]])
    return jac

def lorenz_coupled(X, t, sigma, r, b, C1, C1x, S, O, C2, C2x, tau):
    rhs = [sigma * (X[1] - X[0]) - C1 * (S*X[3] - O), r*X[0] - X[1] - X[0]*X[2] + C1 * (S*X[4] - O), X[0]*X[1] - b*X[2] + C1x*S*X[5], (sigma * (X[4] - X[3]) - C2 * (X[0] + O)) * tau, (r*X[3] - X[4] - S*X[3]*X[5] + C2 * (X[1] + O)) * tau, (S*X[3]*X[5] - b*X[5] + C2x*X[2]) * tau]
    return rhs

#Initial conditions
X0 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

#maiximum time
t_max = 50
t = np.linspace(0, t_max, 1000*t_max + 1)

#parameters
sigma = 10
r = 28
b = 8/3
tau = 0.1
S = 0.5
C1 = 1
C2 = 1
C1x = 1
C2x = 1
O = -11

#solve function
X, sol6 = odeint(lorenz_coupled, X0, t, args=(sigma, r, b, C1, C1x, S, O, C2, C2x, tau), Dfun=coupled_jac, full_output=True)

x6_a, y6_a, z6_a, x6_b, y6_b, z6_b = sol6.y

# time 
t = np.linspace(0, t_max, 10*t_max + 1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8)) #specify the size of plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')

#plot the fast equations
ax.plot(x6_a, y6_a, z6_a)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.title("The Fast Coupled Lorenz Attractor")

#plot the slow coupled equations
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
ax.plot(x6_b, y6_b, z6_b)

#title and axis label
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.title("The Slow Coupled Lorenz Attractor")
```

Comment: What is it odeint function ? is it returns dictionary? Try sol6["y"]

Comment: It means [`odeint` returns a dict as its second return value](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), and you're trying to access `.y` on a dict, and that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Mammadli odeint is a function that solves systems of differential equations. It doesn't work with sol6["y"] I'm afraid.

Comment: @deceze okay, thanks! Would you know what would work instead?

Answer (score 1):

## Note 0

Some errors are more difficult to understand than others.

I am going to "baby" you a little bit, because most programmers would understand your error message (`dict has no attribute named 'y'`)

Please forgive me if the following discussion seems "too easy," or simplistic.

## Note 1

The following code will produce the same error as your code:

```python
sol6 = dict()    
z = sol6.y
```

The error message you received was:

```python
'dict' object has no attribute 'y'
```

It is easier to tell what the mistake you made in your programming if you eliminate all of the extraneous code.

Whenever a python script is not working, a very useful approach is to:

1. Save a back-up copy of your code.
2. Copy and paste your python script into a new file
3. delete a small piece of code
4. re-run the script
5. act based on changes in error message:
   a. If the error goes away:
   * put the deleted code back in.
   * Then, go to step 3 (delete code)
   b. If the same error message is displayed, continue deleting code (go to step 3).

The goal is to "***whittle***" away all of the code untill only the mistake remains.

If your script is hundreds of lines long, it is too difficult to find the mistake.

Try to create the least amount of python code possible which reproduces the same error message.

## Note 2

Why you have an error is very obvious to programmer comfortable with using something called a "***class***".

> The dictionary class has no member variables or methods, named "`y`"

You would have almost the same error in C++, Java, or any other language, not just Python.

A "***class***" represents a complex thing, such as a human person.
The "***member variables***" of a class record short simple facts about the more complicated "***class***"
A first name is an example of a good member variable for a `Person` class

A class is like a fill-in-the-blank sheet which records small facts.
For example, a `JobApplicant` class might have:

- a job applicant's first name
- an applicant's last name
- an applicant's age
- an applicant's phone number
- a job applicant's email address.
- etc...

Suppose that someone is writing code for a website where people buy and sell houses.  You might write a class named `House` which stores statistics about a house for sale:

```
class House:
    * number of bedrooms 
    * number of bathrooms
    * square footage of the house    
    * asking price to buy the house     
    * mailing address/location of the house
    * etc...
```

A class's ***member variables*** are usually things (not actions), such as:

- mass
- velocity
- color
- temperature

class "***methods***" are functions for manipulating the member variables. ***Nethods*** are actions, such as:

- change_first_name
- change_phone_number
- delete
- insert
- rotate
- reflect
- translate
- enlargen
- shrink

#### WHAT IS A "CLASS INSTANCE" or "OBJECT"?

Below are some vocabulary words:

- ***instance of a class***
- ***class object***
- ***object***

All of the above terms mean the same thing.

> An ***instance of a class***  is like a job application will all of the information filled-in.
> An ***instance***/***object*** of a job application might say "first name" and also says "Sarah"

#### CLASS

> A ***class*** is like a paper job-application form which has not been filled-out yet.
> A ***class*** says "first name" and there is a blank line.
> A ***class*** usually does **NOT** specify what a person's first name actually is (Robby, John, Sarah, Ian, Fred, etc...)

#### Pseudocode for classes:

The following is "***pseudo-code***."
***pseudo-code*** is easier to read than python.
If English is at one end of a spectrum, and python is the other end of the spectrum, then "pseudo-code" is somewhere in the middle of the spectrum.

```
begin class named `Rectangle`:

    begin member variables:

        integer my_length;
        integer my_width;

    end of member variables.

    begin methods:

        def get_area():
            return my_length * my_width;

    end of methods.   
end of class named 'Rectangle'
```

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
Robby = Rectangle(4, 8);
w = Robby.my_width;
```

I will translate the code above into English:

1. Construct a new Rectangle having `width = 4` and `length = 8`
2. store the new Rectangle in a hotel room named `Robby`
3. get the `my_width` variable from `Robby`
4. Put the `my_width` variable from `Robby`

Note that code like the following:

```python
Robby.my_width
Robby.get_width()
```

means "***get the width of Robby***" in English.

Something like `x = Robby.favorite_ice_cream_flavor` makes no sense because rectangles do not have a ***favorite ice cream flavor.

Recall that `Robby` is a rectangle.

Your code is something like this:

```
this_dict = {
    "brand": "Ford",
    "model": "Mustang",
    "year": 1964
 }
 blah = this_dict.y
```

Dictionaries, such as `this_dict` do ***NOT*** have member variables named `y`

A dictionary is like a table of inputs and outputs:

```
+-------+---------+
| INPUT | OUTPUT  |
+-------+---------+
| A     | APPLE   |
| B     | BANANA  |
| C     | CHARLIE |
+-------+---------+

+-------+--------+
| INPUT | OUTPUT |
+-------+--------+
| x     |   54.1 |
| y     |   15.3 |
| z     |   99.3 |
+-------+--------+
```

A dictionary is essentially a "look-up table."
You search the input column for an a specific input.
Then you follow the row to see what the output is.

A python "***dictionary***" is lot like a finite function from mathematics.
There are inputs, and output.

Python dictionaries are very finite. Try to keep the number of elements less than `10,000`
even `10,000` is pushing the boundaries a little bit.

Computer programming "functions" are neither like functions from math class, nor are they like dictionaries.

A computer programming "***function***" is like a cook-book recipe.
A computer programming "***function***" explains how to bake a cake.
A computer programming "***function***" is not very finite (infinitely many inputs are possible)

Anyway, python dictionaries don't have an attribute named `y` for the same reason rectangles do not have an attribute named `favorite flavor of ice-cream`. It does not make any sense.

The major difference between a "dictionary" and an "array" is that:

- the inputs to an ***array*** are always whole numbers 1, 2, 3, .... n
- the inputs to a ***dictionary*** might be whole numbers, but they could be other things, such as English words: "red", "blue", "orange".

Below is an example of how to create dictionary, and how to use it afterwards:

```
student_grades = {
    "Joe McCormic": 95.7
    "Lance Armstrong": 87.4,
    "Sarah McPherson": 99.83
    "Kenneth Moer": 77.1
 }
 
def number_to_letter(number: float):
    number = float(number)
    if number > 90:
        return "-A"
    return "F"

    # if number <= 90
    #     return "F"

Joe_McCormic_number = student_grades["Joe McCormic"]

print("Joe_McCormic_number = ", Joe_McCormic_number)

Joe_McCormic_letter_grade = number_to_letter(Joe_McCormic_number)
```

Anyway, dictionaries do not have an attribute named `y`.

Attributes always go to the right of the dot (`.`):

```python
    object.attribute

    my_house.number_of_bedrooms

    Sarah.first_name

    Sarah.phone_number

    my_car.year_of_manufacter
```

Below is a list of some of the attributes which a dictionary does have:
`y` is ***not*** a valid dictionary attribute.

> - `clear()`   deletes/clears all of the elements from the dictionary.
>
>   ```python
>   car_dict = {               #
>       "brand": "Ford",       #
>       "model": "Mustang",    #
>       "year": 1964           #
>   }                          #
>                              #
>   print(len(car_dict))       # prints '3'
>   car_dict.clear()           # deletes everything from the dictionary
>   print(len(car_dict))       # prints '0'
>   ```
> - `__len__()` "***len***" stands for "***length***". The `__len__()` method outputs the ***length*** the dictionary. In other words, it outputs the number of allowed inputs to the dictionary.
>
>   ```python
>   car_dict = {               #
>       "brand": "Ford",       #
>       "model": "Mustang",    #
>       "year": 1964           #
>   }                          #
>                              #
>   print(len(car_dict))       # prints '3'
>   print(car_dict.__len__())  # equivalent to the above
>   ```
> - `copy()` Returns a copy of the dictionary.
>
>   ```python
>   new_dict = old_dict.copy()
>   ```
>
> - `fromkeys()`    Returns a dictionary with the specified keys and value
> - `get()` Returns the value of the specified key
> - `items()`   Returns a list containing a tuple for each key value pair
> - `keys()`    Returns a list containing the dictionary's keys
> - `pop()` Removes the element with the specified key
> - `popitem()` Removes the last inserted key-value pair
> - `setdefault()`  Returns the value of the specified key. If the key does not exist: insert the key, with the specified value
> - `update()`  Updates the dictionary with the specified key-value pairs
> - `values()`  Returns a list of all the values in the dictionary

The bottom two lines in the following code snippet are equivalent:

```
d = dict()
d["ham"] = 83

# The following two lines are equivalent:   
x = d["ham"]
x = d.__getitem__("ham")
```

I am just trying to show that everything involving dictionaries involves accessing attributes of the dictionary. Even the  `[]` operator is actually just the `__getitem__` attribute.

There is no attribute of a dictionary named `y`

```
d = dict()
temp_var = d.y
```

#### ERROR

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Comment: this was incredibly useful - thank you very much!! I think I get what my error actually means now. Is there anyway to find out what attributes do exist in my dictionary? As I am still struggling to plot my results. Thanks again for your help